# How to change order of menu items in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function, menu, menuitem

Hello I have a main menu in my website but I add one item that lists all categories in functions.php

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'category_list', 10, 2);
function category_list($items, $args)
{
    if( $args->theme_location == 'header' )
    {
        $items .= '<li id="menu-item-184" class="parent menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-184"><a href=""#"">Kategorie</a><ul class="sub-menu">';
        $categories = get_categories();
        foreach ($categories as $category)
        {
            $option = '<li><a href="'.get_category_link( $category->term_id ).'">';
            $option .= $category->cat_name;
            $option .= '</a></li>';
            $items .= $option;
        }

        $items .= '</ul></li>';
    }
    return $items;
}
```

How I can change the order of this item. I can't see it in Appearance->menu I want to move it to second position in menu.

Comment: Just drag and drop menus to change their order

Comment: Man I wrote that I dont have this item in appearance so I can't drag it. How can I add item to menu from functions.php?

Comment: Second Position Means ???

Comment: Categories are appear on site but I dont have this item in menu in control panel how can I add it to menu.